# How to escape && in yaml correctly

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run following line in my gitlab pipeline:

```
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

I tested the command in a Ubuntu terminal and it works fine there.

I tried following lines in my gitlab-ci.yml file but without success:

```
script:
  - "[ -s \"$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh\" ] && \. \"$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh\""   # escaping the full line with double quotation marks and then only escaping the quotation marks inside the line -> is marked as invalid yml by gitlab: " found unknown escape character while parsing a quoted scalar"
  - \[ -s \"$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh\" ] &amp;&amp; \\. \"$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh\"   # escaping each special character and replacing the ampersands with &amp; -> fails with: syntax error: unexpected "&"
  - "[ -s \"$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh\" ] &amp;&amp; \. \"$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh\""  # this was marked as invalid yml syntax by gitlab ("found unknown escape character while parsing a quoted scalar")
```

Comment: The first one would work if it wasn’t for `\.`. Have you tried escaping the backslash, i.e. `\\.`? (What it `\.` supposed to do here anyway? In a (POSIX) shell that’s equivalent to just `.`; what’s the backslash for?!)

Comment: `&amp;` doesn’t work because that’s an XML/HTML thing, and YAML is neither of those.

Comment: Single quotes around the whole thing works, and you don’t have to escape anything. A [block scalar](https://yaml-multiline.info) would also work, again without escaping. Just escaping the first `[` seems to work as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following line worked after reading Biffen's comment:

```
- "[ -s \"$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh\" ] && . \"$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh\""
```

So the problem was the escaped . that didn't need to be escaped anymore since I wrapped the command in double quotes.